# how to properly cleanup useEffect that contain async graphql operation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, graphql

I am using graphql/apollo and react.

I have the following code

```
  const [state, setState] = useState(undefined);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const workspace = await getFirstWorkspace();
        // Do Something
        setState(withSomething)
      } catch (error) {
        // Do Something Else
        setState(withErrorSomething)
      }
    })();
  }, [generateLink, getFirstWorkspace, masterDataStoreId]);
```

now, this worked fine until I updated some packages, I currently get thrown this error.

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: signal is aborted without reason

From what I understand my useEffect throw this when the component is unmounted an the query didn't finish to run.

Now, this cause my catch to always trigger at least once, cause it looks like when the effect is run again cause one of the dep changed, it fail.

I """ fixed """ it by doing

```
  const [state, setState] = useState(undefined);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const workspace = await getFirstWorkspace();
        // Do Something
        setState(withSomething)
      } catch (error) {
        // Do Something Else
        if ((error as any)?.name === 'AbortError') {
          return;
        }
        setState(withErrorSomething)
      }
    })();
  }, [generateLink, getFirstWorkspace, masterDataStoreId]);
```

And not assign any state in case the error is an abort. But I couldn't find any proper solution or I don't understand why this is problematic before and not now, I did update some package but none mention a change of behavior on this end.

My question is, what should I do to do thing correctly ?

Comment: *"From what I understand my useEffect throw this when the component is unmounted an the query didn't finish to run."* What makes you think that? Do you have a reference for that? I've never seen that error from React. It looks like something else.

Comment: removing the promise from the effect remove this error. Basically all useEffect containing async operation now throw this error on page changes. It might be due to some `graphql` update maybe, or the `router` update, or `useEffect` themselves. But I couldn't find a good solution to work with this and reverting graphql and react router dom to previous versions still throw this error, so I don't really understand where it come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the error you've quoted is coming from React. React *used* to complain if you did a state update in a component that was no longer mounted, but the error message it used was *"Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application."* But recent versions of React don't do that because the React team decided it was too fussy.

Still, answering the question as asked:

1. ***If*** `getFirstWorkspace` offers a way to tell it to cancel what it's doing, you'd do that. For instance, **if** it supported `AbortSignal`, you might do this:

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
       // *** Create a controller and get its signal
       const controller = new AbortController();
       const { signal } = controller;
       (async () => {
           try {
               // *** Pass the signal to `getFirstWorkspace`
               const workspace = await getFirstWorkspace(signal);
               // *** Only do something if the signal isn't aborted
               if (!signal.aborted) {
                   // Do Something
                   setState(withSomething);
               }
           } catch (error) {
               // *** Only do something if the signal isn't aborted
               if (!signal.aborted) {
                   // Do Something Else
                   setState(withErrorSomething);
               }
           }
       })();
       return () => {
           // *** Abort the signal on cleanup
           controller.abort();
       };
   }, [generateLink, getFirstWorkspace, masterDataStoreId]);
   ```

   ...or similar if it doesn't support `AbortSignal` specifically but does provide some other way of cancelling its work.
2. If it doesn't, you could fall back to a flag telling you not to use the result:

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
       // *** Start with a flag set to `false`
       let cancelled = false;
       (async () => {
           try {
               const workspace = await getFirstWorkspace();
               // *** Only do something if the flag is still `false`
               if (!cancelled) {
                   // Do Something
                   setState(withSomething);
               }
           } catch (error) {
               // *** Only do something if the flag is still `false`
               if (!cancelled) {
                   // Do Something Else
                   setState(withErrorSomething);
               }
           }
       })();
       return () => {
           // *** Set the flag on cleanup
           cancelled = true;
       };
   }, [generateLink, getFirstWorkspace, masterDataStoreId]);
   ```

It's better to actually cancel the work if you can, but it's fine to have a fallback boolean if you can't. Just don't *assume* you can't, be sure to check first. :-)

---

Side note: I love `async`/`await`, but when you're doing just a single call and getting a promise, doing an `async` wrapper and `try`/`catch` around `await` can be a bit overkill. FWIW, just using the promise directly looks like this (using the flag in this case, but it works just as well with the controller/signal):

```
useEffect(() => {
    let cancelled = false;
    getFirstWorkspace().then(
        (workspace) => {
            if (!cancelled) {
                // Do Something
                setState(withSomething);
            }
        },
        (error) => {
            if (!cancelled) {
                // Do Something Else
                setState(withErrorSomething);
            }
        }
    );
    return () => {
        cancelled = true;
    };
}, [generateLink, getFirstWorkspace, masterDataStoreId]);
```

Answer (score 0):

U could make use of AbortController

```
  const [state, setState] = useState(undefined);
  useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const signal = controller.signal;
    (async () => {
      try {
        const workspace = await getFirstWorkspace(signal);
        // Do Something
        setState(withSomething)
      } catch (error) {
        // Do Something Else
        setState(withErrorSomething)
      }
    })();
    return =()=>Controller.abort();
  }, [generateLink, getFirstWorkspace, masterDataStoreId]);
```